# TLSIOException connecting over Https on Blackberry Torch 9810 and 9860

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to connect over Https connection on Torch 9810 and 9860 but I am getting [TLSIOException](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/cldc/io/ssl/TLSIOException.html). I tested the code on 9700 OS v6.0 and it is running successfully on it. But the issue is only reproducable on 9810 and  9860 (both Torch devices). I saw a few threads on this issue but no solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

TLSIOException has a method getException() which will return a TLSException.   If you then look at that TLSException, you should be able to learn more about the problem.  For example, there are two subclasess of TLSException - [TLSAlertException](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/tls/TLSAlertException.html) and [TLSCancelException](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/cldc/io/ssl/TLSCancelException.html).
If your TLSException is actually a TLSAlertException, you can look at the alert properties to learn more about the problem.